# Apache flink: Lazy load from save point for RocksDB backend

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb

We want to use Apache Flink with RocksDB backend (HDFS) for stateful stream processing. However, our application state (keyed state) will be in the order of terabytes.

From what I understand, when we restore a job from a savepoint, all the operator state data will be shipped from the savepoint location on HDFS to each of the task managers. If the state is in the order of terabytes, then every deployment will result in a very long downtime if all this state needs to be transferred.

I wanted to understand, if in the case of RocksDB, it is possible to configure lazy loading, wherein keyed state is retrieved from HDFS as and when required, and then cached on the local disk.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RocksDB and configure your Flink cluster to use local recovery, which you can read about [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/large_state_tuning.html#task-local-recovery), then a copy of the RocksDB files will be kept on each task manager's local disk, and recovery will be almost immediate (except for any new nodes that have to be spun up).

However, this doesn't really apply to savepoints, as this mechanism requires incremental snapshots to really work well.

You may want to read that whole page of the docs, which is about [how to configure and tune applications that use large amounts of state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/large_state_tuning.html).

Comment: Hi @David Anderson: Thank you for your reply. I went through the documentation that you linked, but there doesn't seem to be anything specific with respects to deployments and savepoints. 

. The book: Stream Processing with Apache Flink mentions: "Users have reported applications with state sizes of multiple terabytes leveraging RocksDBStateBackend"

Does this mean these users are living with multiple hours down time during deployments? Or is there anyway to reduce this duration.

Comment: Many users with huge state aren't using savepoints for deployments. They are using externalized checkpoints for the reason you've pointed out.

Comment: Oh thank you, I did not know about externalized checkpoints! But as per: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/checkpoints.html#externalized-checkpoints, it seems like if we use externalized checkpoints we can never add or remove nodes from the cluster? Parallelism will have to remain constant. (It says: Externalized checkpoints... do not support Flink specific features like rescaling).

Comment: Back then we didn’t want to commit to externalized checkpoints remaining compatible with rescaling, but they are and we’ve since relaxed our position on this point.

Comment: Thank you @David Anderson. One last question.. so this means that if we use externalized checkpoints: Deployments are quick, but rescaling would still mean a downtime since the state now needs to be shipped to the new node ? Is there any existing state backend that does this state load lazily ?

Comment: I don't think so.