# Flink - Lazy start with operators working during savepoint startup

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Apache Flink with `RocksDBStateBackend` and going through some trouble when the job is restarted using a savepoint.

Apparently, it takes some time for the state to be ready again, but even though the state isn't ready yet, DataStreams from Kafka seems to be moving data around, which causes some invalid misses as the state isn't ready yet for my `KeyedProcessFunction`.

Is it the expected behavior? I couldn't find anything in the documentation, and apparently, no related configuration.

The ideal for us would be to have the state fully ready to be queried before any data is moved.

For example, this shows that during a deployment, the `estimate_num_keys` metric was slowly increasing.

[image: Estimate Number of Keys during a Deployment]

However, if we look at an application counter from an operator, they were working during that "warm-up phase".

[image: Application Metric showing process]

I found some discussion here [Apache flink: Lazy load from save point for RocksDB backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387149/apache-flink-lazy-load-from-save-point-for-rocksdb-backend) where it was suggested to use Externalized Checkpoints.

I will look into it, but currently, our state isn't too big (~150 GB), so I am not sure if that is the only path to try.

Comment: [Externalized checkpoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/checkpoints/#externalized-checkpoints) improved this behavior. Not sure if that can be achieved using Savepoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a Flink job that uses RocksDB from a savepoint is an expensive operation, as all of the state must first be loaded from the savepoint into new RocksDB instances. On the other hand, if you use a retained, incremental checkpoint, then the SST files in that checkpoint can be used directly by RocksDB, leading to must faster start-up times.

But, while it's normal for starting from a savepoint to be expensive, this shouldn't lead to any errors or dropped data.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like we were having some data loss. The errors were related to the state not being ready yet, but operators were already being triggered. On the other hand, and it's a bit hard to prove because our entries have TTL, but they were not too aggressive and every savepoint was followed by this behavior of loading the same or more keys than we had before, and slowly reducing the entries saved. (I am using Flink 1.11.2 and looking into migrating to 1.13). Anyway, retaining and using externalized checkpoints now and seems very smooth.

Comment: Hook: A bit afraid of savepointing to upgrade to 1.13. Can I use checkpoint recovery across versions? The documentation seems to lead me to go through the stop with the savepoint path.

Comment: I'm not sure what you saw, but no data can move before the state has been restored.

Comment: Re using retained checkpoints to migrate state across a Flink upgrade: The consensus is that this should work for an upgrade from Flink 1.11 to 1.13, but it's risky. There's no guarantee this will work without data loss, and there are no tests.